# Removing identical terms in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a function that can remove duplicates from an array of characters. The problem is that the function works for a certain number of characters, but if the array a lot of terms, then the program does not work right. Also, if the duplicate terms are right next to each other, the program does not remove it.

```
void delete_repeats(char array[],int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            if(array[i] == array[j] || !((array[j] >= 97) && (array[j] <= 122))){
                for(int k = j; k < size; k++){
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                    size--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

original array contains: `Mary had a little lamp`

After program is run: `maryhdliitttlelaampp`

Comment: Seriously, what's up these days with writing C in the title and tagging C++? Please make up your mind which language you're writing in.

Comment: Well, at least the user did not tag it C and C++.

Comment: Oh, and Mary had a "lamb", not "lamp" :D

Comment: *if* you're using C++, consider `std::set<char>`

Comment: And all this time I thought Mary and a lamb.

Comment: .. but she lost it the dark for absence of a lamp?

Comment: This might be easier to read: `if (array[i] == array[j] || (array[j] < 97 || array[j] > 122))` which in turn could be written as `if (array[i] == array[j] || array[j] < 97 || array[j] > 122)` …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the size out of that loop into the outer loop:

```
void delete_repeats(char array[],int size){
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
        if(array[i] == array[j] || !((array[j] >= 97) && (array[j] <= 122))){
            for(int k = j; k < size; k++){
                array[k] = array[k + 1];
            }
            size--;
        }

    }
  }
}

INPUT: Mary had a little lamb
OUTPUT:  Maryhdlitemb
```

Answer (score 0):

You decrease `size` too often. Decrease `size` after you moved the array's content.